# Fast mutable objects in Erlang

Tags: erlang

What is the best approach to store and manage high-performance mutable objects in Erlang? Assume that I want to write really simple online game server with realtime gameplay. Somehow I need to represent player's state in Erlang memory. For example, it could be just a simple tuple like

```
{name, "Bob", health, 100, ammo, 50, score, 0}
```

These objects should be stored for a long time (at least while the user session is alive), should be mutable (since players can interact to each other, like shoot each other, kill, heal, etc), and should be high-performance (since the game is realtime but not step-by-step). So I don't want to keep this data in SQL or Mnesia. What kind of data structures is the best approach?

Comment: Don't forget that the usual way to store data that need frequent access in erlang is in the process state (the parameters of the main loop). If you have one process per player, and one process per game element(depending on your game it can be one level, one screen or any relevant part of your game). All those long living processes are recursive, so you can "modify" any element by calling recursively the process with the new state as parameter. Erlang OTP provide very useful behavior for this purpose, gen_fsm and gen_server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a look at the [ETS-module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) (Erlang Term Storage). It is an in-memory key-value-store and, as the name suggests, it can store erlang-terms in hashmap/tree-structures. I recommend reading [this article](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/ets), it has nice examples and is written for beginners.

With ETS, you can have 4 types of storage:

- `set` -- no order, no duplication, constant-time access
- `ordered_set` -- ordered, no duplication, O(log N)-time access
- `bag` -- no order, duplicate keys (but not values), O(log N)-time access
- `duplicate_bag` -- no order, duplicate keys and values, O(log N)-time access

If you need to have persistent long-term storage, try the [DETS-Module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dets.html).

Comment: Looks like it's just what I was looking for, thanks :)